# open form and usercontrol and change user control by button winform c#

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a c# form with 5 tabs which includes an user control. I have a button in this control, and I want that when the user clicks on the button, another user control will be opened and change the tab.

my form with 5 tabs

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Accueil());
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Outils());
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Utilitaires());
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Extras());
        PanelSlider.Controls.Add(new Options());
        Accueil_menuStrip.Renderer = new MyMenuRenderer_Menu();

        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        Shown += Form1_Shown;

    }
```

the tab Accueil call user control Accueil

my button click user control Acceuil in my form

```
        public void UtilsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelSlider.Controls.Find("Utilitaires", false)[0].BringToFront();
    }
```

the tab Utilitaires call user control Utilitaires

```
        public Utilitaires()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Project1());
        PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Project2());
        PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Project3());
    }
```

In the user control Utilitaires i can call 3 others user control

How i can directly call project 3 from my user control Accueil and select the tab utilitaires ?

I am able to select the utilitaires tab directly by the button in my acceuil user control but NO the project3 usercontrol

```
        public void btn_UserFrame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 essai = (Form1)this.FindForm();
        essai.UtilsBtn.PerformClick();

        how to call project3 in my utilitaires usercontrol...?
    }
```

Always show project1 in my utilitaires usercontrol no project3... I do not know how to do...

RESUME:

- Form with 5 tabs which includes an usercontrol PanelSlider
- Button UserFrame in the usercontrol PanelSlider

When i click on the button UserFrame i want to change the tab form and show the usercontrol Utilitaires with the PanelSlider_Utils Project3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding Project3 with no name:

```
PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(new Project3());
```

You'd have to iterate over all the controls and look for a match based on TYPE. Another option would be to set the `Name` property and then use `Controls.Find()` like you're already doing.

Why don't you store those references, though?

```
private Project1 p1 = new Project1();
private Project2 p2 = new Project2();
private Project3 p3 = new Project3();

public Utilitaires()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    p1.Name = "p1";
    p2.Name = "p2";
    p3.Name = "p3";

    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(p1);
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(p2);
    PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Add(p3);
}
```

Now you can use "p1", "p2", and "p3" directly to manipulate them somehow...

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind for your answer BUT if i add PanelSlider_Utils.Controls.Find("p3", false)[0].BringToFront(); into my button click usercontrol Acceuil i have this error : System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Do you have some solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Because "p3" is not the name of that control,  it is simply the name of the variable referencing it. If you want to search for it like that, then set the name with: `p3.Name = "p3";`